# Store Javascript object in $_SESSION by Ajax. Array vs JSON string

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, session

I'm sending an Ajax request which sends an object `objectVariable` to a PHP file:

```
$.post(url, {action : 'function' , object : objectVariable });
```

Then, the PHP file will store `objectVariable` in `$_SESSION['objectVariable']` (I'm omitting validation to make it clear):

```
function function_callback() {

    if(!session_id()) 
        session_start();

    $_SESSION['objectVariable'] = $_POST['objectVariable'];
}
```

When the user goes to other page of the site, the `$_SESSION['objectVariable']` will be sent from PHP to the user by Ajax again. 
Here, I should encode the array stored in `$_SESSION['objectVariable']` to a JSON string:

```
//inside other Axax callback function
echo json_encode($_SESSION['objectVariable']);
```

That's working right, but I also could store a JSON string into `$_SESSION['objectVariable']`:

```
function function_callback() {

    if(!session_id()) 
        session_start();

    $_SESSION['objectVariable'] = json_encode($_POST['objectVariable']);
}
```

And after, just `echo $_SESSION['objectVariable']` to send it to the Javascript file.

I wonder what would be a better way: store an array in `$_SESSION['objectVariable']`, or store a JSON string.

Any suggestion about it?

Answer (score 1):

When sending data between Javascript/PHP I always keep it encoded as a JSON string. It makes things simpler. In fact, I would just `JSON.stringify()` it right away when you send it to the server the 1st time.

This way you also will always know what type the data will be.

Comment: Using objects makes validation more simply in my case. Anyway, I decided to use a string to store it in `$_SESSION`. Thanks for your suggestion.